# How do make payment invoice on the bases of payment method e.g monthly, quarterly, annually

Tags: sql

I am going to make a system generated invoice, I have two tables tblpayment and tblinvoice. The scenario is the invoice is generated the invoice data insert into tblinvoice with bit OFF. Once the payment has been done the bit ON and data insert into tblpayment.

How can I check the invoice of particular customer has been generated or not, so that data will not be duplicated.

Comment: Use a SQL `WHERE`

Comment: or a NOT EXISTS condition